# How to delete items in a list based on another list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
all_words_merged = ['ego', 'femina', 'incenderare', 'tuus', 'casa', 'et',
                    'cutullus', 'incipere', 'et', 'wingardium', 'leviosa']
class_words_merged = ['femina', 'incenderare', 'incipere', 'wingardium']
```

I want to take `all_words_merged` and delete any instances that occur in `class_words_merged`. The resulting list should be:

```
result = ['ego', 'tuus', 'casa', 'et', 'cutullus', 'et', 'leviosa']
```

I tried the code below but it returned an empty list:

```
result = [x for x in class_words_merged if x[0] in all_words_merged]
```

Comment: should 'et' be duplicated? is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should iterate over `all_words_merged` and only include words not in `class_words_merged`

```
result = [x for x in all_words_merged if x not in class_words_merged]
```

Output:

```
['ego', 'tuus', 'casa', 'et', 'cutullus', 'et', 'leviosa']
```

**EDIT**

If `class_words_merged` can contain duplicates then using `set` first will give better performance.

```
cwm_set = set(class_words_merged)
result = [x for x in all_words_merged if x not in cwm_set]
```

Comment: You'll get slightly better performance for long lists if you first do `cwm_set = set(class_words_merged)` and then `... x not in cwm_set]`.

Answer (score 4):

If `class_words_merged` is large, it would speed up things to convert it into a set first:

```
>>> to_remove = set(class_words_merged)
>>> [word for word in all_words_merged if word not in to_remove]
['ego', 'tuus', 'casa', 'et', 'cutullus', 'et', 'leviosa']
```

#### Some timings

100 times larger:

```
large_class_words_merged = class_words_merged * 100
```

Creating as set first:

```
%%timeit
to_remove = set(large_class_words_merged)
[word for word in all_words_merged if word not in to_remove]
1000 loops, best of 3: 493 µs per loop
```

and going through the list repeatedly:

```
%timeit [word for word in all_words_merged if word not in large_class_words_merged]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop
```

Hint:

`%timeit` and `%%imeit` are IPython  magic commands I am using in Jupyter a notebook.

Comment: Just for the record: using sets will loose the original ordering - whether this is a problem or not depending on the concrete use case, but I thought I might mention it nonetheless ;)

Comment: Yes, converting into a set removes the order. But it does not matter here because this is the goal: "I want to take `all_words_merged` and delete any instances that occur in `class_words_merged`". The order of `all_words_merged` is preserved. The order of `class_words_merged` does not matter for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `filter` built-in method, like so:

```
>>> all_words_merged = ['ego', 'femina', 'incenderare', 'tuus', 'casa', 'et', 'cutullus', 'incipere', 'et', 'wingardium', 'leviosa']
>>> class_words_merged = ['femina', 'incenderare', 'incipere', 'wingardium']
>>>
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x not in class_words_merged, all_words_merged))
['ego', 'tuus', 'casa', 'et', 'cutullus', 'et', 'leviosa']
```

`list` is necessary with Python3 as `filter` generate a *filter object*, whereas in Python2, that's not required, just:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in class_words_merged, all_words_merged)
```

EDIT:

This is of course not the optimized way, as you have to go over converting the generator into lists, you can guess it through timing profile:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='list(filter(lambda x: x not in c, a))', globals={'a':all_words_merged, 'c':class_words_merged})
2.6026250364160717
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[x for x in a if x not in c]', globals={'a':all_words_merged, 'c':class_words_merged})
1.3826178676799827
```